# Quick Fix Java Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Am I just to blind to see the solution?

```
sampleSum = 0;
for(int x : sampleWeights)
   sampleSum += x;

population = new int[sampleSum];
int z = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < nsamples; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < sampleWeights[i]; j++) 
{
    population[z] = i;
    z++;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please format the code - it does cure blindness for us :-)

Comment: More code necessary. Where did: nsamples come from?  Also, did you instantiate  population[z]?  Also, what line do you get your out of bounds exception?

Comment: There isn't enough code here, where is nsamples declared (among other things)?  Maybe that's > sampleWeights.length.

Comment: Any of the weights negative (or causes an overflow)?

Comment: Actually it's a friends code sample :) Getting the rest of the code now :)

Comment: Nested loops would be easier to read written as for (int x : sampleWeights) { for (int j=0; j<x; ++j) { ... } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all sampleWeights is zero sampleSum will be zero and population.length=0. So when you do population[z] there will be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: If sampleWeights[i] is zero, there will be no population[z] execution.

Comment: you are right, but if sampleWeight[0]=1 and sampleWeight[1]=-1, sampleSum will be zero and we got an Exception

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have N integers, N = # Samples x # weights/Sample(i)?

If this is the case, from where did you get the sampleWeights array (or List given autoboxing of Integers)?

Run your code again with some System.out.println's to gather debug info, and you'll quickly see what's wrong.